# Ubuntu Memory Test

Tags: 12.04, installation, ram, memory-test

Several months ago I was having issues with a Windows PC. I booted from and Ubuntu CD, performed a memory test, and found that I had some bad RAM.

I'm having some issues with another PC, so I downloaded 12.04 and booted from the CD. The screen that comes up simply gives me the option to Try or Install. Where can I find the memory test?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Press <kbd>ESC</kbd> while starting the i386 desktop CD,  and choose `Test memory`.

Comment: That basically runs memtest86+

Comment: No way to run install it in a standard bootable system?

Answer (score 5):

Why dont you use memtest86+(http://www.memtest.org/)?!
Since I thought to remember you had to have "empty" ram.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using [memtester](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/memtester):

> **`memtester`** Utility
>      for testing the memory subsystem

#### Install

sudo apt-get install memtester

#### Usage

> please add working examples